# Integrate swagger typescript-fetch api into aurelia-cli tyepscript project

Tags: typescript, npm, swagger, aurelia

For a web project I want to create a swagger (open api) api to use for both, the backend server (go) and the frontend (aurela-cli + typescript).

The `swagger-codegen` tool supports the following client generators
- typescript-angular
- typescript-angular2
- typescript-node
- typescript-fetch

Now, the first three obviously do not apply to this problem so I am left with `typescript-fetch`. To generate the client from a `swagger.yml` I use the following:
`swagger-codegen generate -i swagger.yml -l typescript-fetch -o api`

This results in a project folder as seen in the [swagger repository](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/samples/client/petstore/typescript-fetch/builds/default).

The questions is how to include this in an aurelia project.

I already ran `npm install` which resulted in a transpiled api.js (and corresponding api.d.ts). I am however, unsure how to proceed next.

1) Where should I put this folder?
- `src/api`
- `node-modules/<fake-module-name>`
-  somewhere else

2) How do I inform aurelia about the 'module' in the `aurelia.json` file?
- `"<fake-module-name>"`
- `"{
        "name": "<fake-module-name>",
        "path": "../node_modules/<fake-module-name>dist",
        "main": "api"
      }`
- something else

The main problem I am hitting is that, even though aurelia.json knows about the api in the  module, the dependencies within this module bring the build process (`au run --watch)` to a halt, as they are somehow looked for in the front-end's `src` directory.

Any help on how to resolve this would be highly appreciated.

P.S. I have a slight feeling that I would have to 'simply' import the api module's dependencies and their dependencies and so on into the aurelia.json...

Comment: Have you tried using Nswag instead for client side codegen? I'm mentioning it because it has a specific Aurelia fetch client implementation. You don't have to use a .NET backend in order for it to work, a swagger.json file should do the trick. see: https://github.com/NSwag/NSwag

Comment: Yes, I have looked into nswag already (just forgot to mention it..). I didn't feel quite comfortable introducing it into our build process since we are not working on Windows and would need Mono or the .NET console library as a dev dependecy.

Comment: BTW: NSwag can also be run on .NET Core on MacOS or Linux...

Answer (score 1):

I modified one of the other TypeScript generators to generate a TypeScript client for the Aurelia Fetch Client:

https://github.com/jeremeevans/typescript-aurelia-fetch-client-generator

My documentation there is pretty awful right now, but the basic steps are:

1. Clone Swagger Codegen: git clone https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen.git
2. Navigate to the swagger-codegen directory and build/install it:

   - mvn clean package
   - mvn install
3. Go back to your git directory and clone the typescript-aurelia-fetch-client-generator: Git clone https://github.com/jeremeevans/typescript-aurelia-fetch-client-generator.git
4. Navigate to the typescript-aurelia-fetch-client-generator directory and build it:

   - mvn package

Then create a config file for your library:

```
{
  "packageName": "MyLibraryName",
  "modelPropertyNaming": "original" // if you want to keep your casing on the models.
}
```

Then to build your TypeScript client, navigate to the Swagger Codegen directory and run:

```
java -cp '../typescript-aurelia-fetch-client-generator/target/typescript-aurelia-fetch-client-swagger-codegen-1.0.0.jar;./modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar' io.swagger.codegen.Codegen -i http://localhost:8080/swagger/docs/v4 -l typescript-aurelia-fetch-client -o c:\temp\OutputFolder -c C:\temp\yourconfig.json
```

Obviously, replace http://localhost:8080/swagger/docs/v4 with the path to your Swagger definition.

If this helped you, please star the repository. Also, contributions are welcome.